# How do i update a label when input box has new value

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to get a label to update when a user enters a value into a text box. I have managed to get the label to update when the slider bar value is changed by the user but i dont have the skill to get it to update when the text box changes.

I tried to write some code but it does not look right at all, can sombody lend me a hand?

Code i tried

```
  $("#MonthlyRent").text({
                textchange: function (event, ui) {
                    update(2, ui.value + '%'); //changed
                }
            });
```

Function to catch change

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#slider").slider({
                range: "min",
                animate: true,
                value: 1,
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                step: 1,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    update(1, ui.value + '%'); //changed
                }
            });

            $("#slider2").slider({
                range: "min",
                animate: true,
                value: 1,
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                step: 1,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    update(2, ui.value + '%'); //changed
                }
            });

            $("#MonthlyRent").text({
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    update(2, ui.value + '%'); //changed
                }
            });

            //Added, set initial value.
            $("#amount").val(0);
            $("#duration").val(0);
            $("#amount-label").text(0);
            $("#duration-label").text(0);
            $("MonthlyRent").text(0);
            update();
        });
```

update function

```
 function update(slider, val) {
            //changed. Now, directly take value from ui.value. if not set (initial, will use current value.)
            var $amount = slider == 1 ? val : $("#amount").val();
            var $duration = slider == 2 ? val : $("#duration").val();
            var $rent = $("#MonthlyRent").val();
            var $amount2 = $amount.replace('%', '');

            /* commented
            $amount = $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );
            $duration = $( "#slider2" ).slider( "value" );
             */
            $total = "£" + ($amount2 + $rent);
            $("#amount").val($amount);
            $("#amount-label").text($amount);
            $("#duration").val($duration);
            $("#duration-label").text($duration);
            $("#total").val($total);
            $("#total-label").text($total);

            $('#slider a').html('<label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> ' + $amount + ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></label>');
            $('#slider2 a').html('<label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> ' + $duration + ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></label>');
        }
```

Comment: java is to javascript as ham is to hamster, it has nothing to do with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect a change on a textbox use the following

http://jsfiddle.net/SrhYh/

```
$('#example').change(function() {
    update();
});

function update() {
    $('#result').text($('#example').val());
}
```

as an alternative listen to keyup

```
$('#example').keyup(function() {
    update();
});

function update() {
    $('#result').text($('#example').val());
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SrhYh/1/

Comment: Change event is only fired (at least on Chrome v34) when you copy / paste, or when you leave the input. If you want to update as soon as user type, you should use keyup / keydown event.

Comment: @holt I know please see my update :), and as per your answer it could be combined into the `.on()` statement although I believe the change method is redundant with keyup present

Comment: thanks! iv been wondering what keyup does haha... now i know :D

Answer (score 1):

Use the event change or keyup:

```
$('#mytextinput').on('change keyup', function (e) { /* You stuff here. */ })
```

Without HTML code, I guessed your input was something like `<input type="text" id="mytextinput" />`, but if it is not you should give more information.